# SPSS chart saved as PNG with OMS or other

Tags: spss

Is there a way to automatically save a chart in SPSS as a png? I need to use syntax not the usual copy and paste or menu procedure. For example with OMS you can save to PDF word etc...
For example:

OMS
 /SELECT CHARTS /DESTINATION FORMAT = DOC  IMAGES = YES  IMAGEFORMAT = JPG CHARTSIZE = 100  OUTFILE = "my chart.doc".

*chart.

OMSEND.

but is there a way to automatically save a chart as a PNG through syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUTPUT EXPORT command can do this.  The OMS IMAGEFORMAT keyword also supports PNG as a graphics type.